# primefaces graphicImage inside CommandLink's style

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

How can I remove the padding that surrounds PrimeFaces' `p:graphicImage` component?

This is my code:

```
<h:commandLink action="distributer/distributersList.xhtml" ajax="false">
    <p:graphicImage  value="/resources/images/image.jpg"
                     style="align:center" width="250" height="327"/>
</h:commandLink>
```

I tried using the following CSS, which removed the border but the gray padding surrounding the image still remains:

```
.ui-commandlink{
    border:none;
    padding:0px;
    border-spacing:0px;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's in the first line in my post :) to remove the padding that surround the p:graphicImage component

Comment: I couldn't reproduce your problem. Maybe the padding you are seeing is due to other CSS stylesheets you are using in the same page?